# Jumping to a topic in a CHM help file without opening another window

Tags: inno-setup, chm, shellexecute, html-help

I'm including a cut-down CHM help with an installer and I want the help button on each page of the installer wizard to call up a different help page.  If I open the help window from one installer wizard page by executing the command `hh.exe -mapid 1234 MyAppCutDownHelp.chm` it works fine, but if I do the same thing later from another wizard page with `hh.exe -mapid 5678 MyAppCutDownHelp.chm` I get that topic OK, but another instance of HH.EXE is started and I then have two help windows, one with topic 1234 and one with topic 5678.

I would like the first invocation of HH.exe to open the CHM help window, and from then on to have subsequent help topics display within the sane help window from the installer.

I don't believe I have access to the same HTML help API from the Inno Setup scripting Pascal that I would normally have from Delphi.

I am at present starting the help engine with

```
ShellExecAsOriginalUser ('open', ExpandConstant ('{tmp}\MyAppCutDownHelp.chm'), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ErrorCode) ;
```

but I imagine that just calls HH.exe.

**Update** Here is my latest attempt based on @Robert's answer:

```
; -- Help Test.iss --

[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
DefaultGroupName=My Program
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: isreadme

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"

[Code]

const
 HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC = 0;
 HH_DISPLAY_TOC =1;
 HH_DISPLAY_INDEX =2;
 HH_HELP_CONTEXT = 15;

function HtmlHelpA (hWndCaller: HWND; pszFile: PAnsiChar; uCommand: UINT; dwData: DWORD): HWnd; 
  external 'HtmlHelpA@hhctrl.ocx stdcall';

function HtmlHelp(hWndCaller: HWND; pszFile: String; uCommand: UINT; dwData: DWORD): HWnd; 
begin
  try
    result := HtmlHelpA(hWndCaller,pszFile,uCommand,dwData);
  except
     MsgBox('Unable To Display Help file.', mbError, MB_OK);    
  end;
end;


function InitializeSetup : Boolean;
begin
  HtmlHelp(0,'MyProg.chm',HH_DISPLAY_TOC,0);
  result := true;

end;
```

Comment: Using your code I don't get anything.   'Myprog.chm' can not be found.  I don't get an error though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `HtmlHelpA` or `HtmlHelpW` function in `hhctrl.ocx`

This is documented in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms670068%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

```
; -- Example1.iss --
; Demonstrates copying 3 files and creating an icon.

; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING .ISS SCRIPT FILES!

[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
DefaultGroupName=My Program
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: isreadme

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"

[Code]
const
 HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC = 0;
 HH_DISPLAY_TOC =1;
 HH_DISPLAY_INDEX =2;
 HH_HELP_CONTEXT = 15;

function HtmlHelpA (hWndCaller: HWND; pszFile: PAnsiChar; uCommand: UINT; dwData: DWORD): HWnd; 
  external 'HtmlHelpA@hhctrl.ocx stdcall';

function HtmlHelp(hWndCaller: HWND; pszFile: String; uCommand: UINT; dwData: DWORD): HWnd; 
begin
  try
    result := HtmlHelpA(hWndCaller,pszFile,uCommand,dwData);
  except
     MsgBox('Unable To Display Help file.', mbError, MB_OK);    
  end;
end;


function InitializeSetup : Boolean;
begin
  HtmlHelp(0,'C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\ISetup.chm',HH_DISPLAY_TOC,0);
  result := true;
end;
```

Comment: Great @Robert.  Just what I wanted.

Comment: @Robert aarrgghh not so fast...  I get error 0xc0000005 in hhctrl.ocx - the try..except doesn't even pick it up - it goes straight to the MS "xxx has encountered an error" dialog.

Comment: How are you calling the function?   In the example I posted it works, I have never actually done this before just wrote an example based on documentation, so I might have something to learn here as well.

Comment: @rossmcm, you should add your code to your _question_, not to @Robert's _answer_.

Comment: @sarnold - well spotted - I misfired

Comment: The only thought that crossed my mind is that the first param is the window of the calling application.     GetDesktopWindow() windows API result might be better to pass here.

Comment: @Robert - I've modified the "Example1.iss" in the InnoSetup package.  This compiles and runs, but doesn't display any help, or give an error... does it work for you? - the code is just your answer with the rest of the script added to get it to compile.

Comment: I just changed Example1.iss (and modified my answer with it)  When i run this on the startup it launches the CHM help file.   I am using Windows 7.

Comment: OK @Robert just tried your example and with minor mod (changed to `C:\Program Files\` for Win XP) it behaves as yours does.  Now I have find out why my other one doesn't work...  Thanks

Comment: Ahaa! @Robert.  `HtmlHelp (0, 'C:\Program Files\Inno Setup 5\ISetup.chm',HH_DISPLAY_TOC,0);` works fine, but `HtmlHelp (0, 'C:\Program Files\Inno Setup 5\ISetup.chm',HH_HELP_CONTEXT,0);` crashes out with MS error. (Context number 0 may not be valid, but I would expect it to be a bit more sociable).

Answer (score 1):

This is much simpler IMHO:

```
Filename: "{win}\hh.exe"; \
    Parameters: "{app}\MeetSchedAssist.chm::/msa-revision-history.htm"; \
    WorkingDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: nowait postinstall runmaximized; \
    Description: "{cm:ViewChangeHistory}"
```

No need for all that code. Just invoke the CHM file using `hh.exe`.

Comment: I don't think this meets the requirement **"without opening another window"**, or does it?

Comment: @DocBrown Don't know! I wrote this answer 4 years ago.